# Can we move developer forum points from one org to another?

Tags: developer-edition, developer-org, forgot-your-password, reset-password

Unfortunately i am not able to login to my old developer org and also can't reset my password. 
Tried sending email to trailhead@salesforce.com, but its saying this address is added to no reply email. so i created a new org.

I was wondering if i can transfer developer forum points to my new org. I was able to transfer my trailhead badges but not sure about develoepr forum points.

Is it possible ? If not, is there any other way to reset my developer accoount ?

Thanks,
Manohar

Comment: As far as I know there's no provision to do so. You might try support, but I don't know if they can/will help.

Comment: Its also worth noting, you can get support to reset your password for you in your developer org.